# HTML to PDF converter in PHP

Tags: html, pdf, converters

To generate pdf from html page I have tried many pdf libraries like **FPDF,HTML2FPDF,CEZPDF,DOMPDF and MPDF** .

But in every pdf library I found some issues which don't produce required layout of the page.

For example in MPDF I found page breaks but it was a nice html to pdf converter.

So kindly suggest me which library should I use to generate pdf? I don't care if it needs to purchase.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder why you haven't tried **[TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/)** which is currently the most stable version. **[Here](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_049.phps)** is the clean example of what you are looking for.

```
<?php

require_once('tcpdf_include.php');
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 049');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 049', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

]$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);

$pdf->AddPage();


$html = '<h1>Test TCPDF Methods in HTML</h1>
<h2 style="color:red;">IMPORTANT:</h2>
<span style="color:red;">If you are using user-generated content, the tcpdf tag can be unsafe.<br />
You can disable this tag by setting to false the <b>K_TCPDF_CALLS_IN_HTML</b> constant on TCPDF configuration file.</span>
<h2>write1DBarcode method in HTML</h2>';

$params = TCPDF_STATIC::serializeTCPDFtagParameters(array('CODE 39', 'C39', '', '', 80, 30, 0.4, array('position'=>'S', 'border'=>true, 'padding'=>4, 'fgcolor'=>array(0,0,0), 'bgcolor'=>array(255,255,255), 'text'=>true, 'font'=>'helvetica', 'fontsize'=>8, 'stretchtext'=>4), 'N'));
$html .= '<tcpdf method="write1DBarcode" params="'.$params.'" />';

$params = TCPDF_STATIC::serializeTCPDFtagParameters(array('CODE 128', 'C128', '', '', 80, 30, 0.4, array('position'=>'S', 'border'=>true, 'padding'=>4, 'fgcolor'=>array(0,0,0), 'bgcolor'=>array(255,255,255), 'text'=>true, 'font'=>'helvetica', 'fontsize'=>8, 'stretchtext'=>4), 'N'));
$html .= '<tcpdf method="write1DBarcode" params="'.$params.'" />';

$html .= '<tcpdf method="AddPage" /><h2>Graphic Functions</h2>';

$params = TCPDF_STATIC::serializeTCPDFtagParameters(array(0));
$html .= '<tcpdf method="SetDrawColor" params="'.$params.'" />';

$params = TCPDF_STATIC::serializeTCPDFtagParameters(array(50, 50, 40, 10, 'DF', array(), array(0,128,255)));
$html .= '<tcpdf method="Rect" params="'.$params.'" />';
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, 0);

$pdf->lastPage();
$pdf->Output('example_049.pdf', 'I');

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this http://www.tcpdf.org/ . Site providing some good examples and also you can design page layout as your own styles

Answer (score 1):

I've used TCPDF and DOMPDF.

**FOR:**

- TCPDF:

  - You can design the page layout very easily
- DOMPDF:

  - almost every css feature support, if you design the page in html, css, the printed pdf will be the same. This is the easiest library available on the internet.
  - you also can use php scripts, and DOMPDF will run it on pdf generation.

**Against:**

- TCPDF:

  - you have to write a lot...
  - very hard to use css
- DOMPDF:

  - on large tables, it has a huge memory consumption, and could crash.
  - tricky page layout design ( header and footer)

Answer (score 0):

Try HTM2PDF - it supports page breaking, single page layouts and many other options.

A [HTML to PDF API](http://htm2pdf.co.uk/html-to-pdf-api) is available for all programming languages as well as a PHP [HTML to PDF SDK](http://htm2pdf.co.uk/html-to-pdf-sdk).

Answer (score -1):

Use this tool. This will be better

http://sourceforge.net/projects/html2fpdf/